# Scala Specs2 Matchers with "aka" doesn't work

Tags: scala, specs2

Scala Specs2 matcher that looks like this (for example):

```
  def haveSizeOf(size: Int): Matcher[ProductElement] = { 
    productElement: ProductElement =>
    val sizeOfproductElement = productElement.size
    sizeOfproductElement aka "size of product element"
  } ^^ beEqualTo(size)
```

And it's execution in the code:

```
updatedProductElement must haveSizeOf(1)
```

Throws error:

> java.lang.Exception:
>   'org.specs2.matcher.ThrownExpectations$$anon$1@6a3b7968'
>
> is not equal to
>
> '1'

What should i have done differently?

**Edit:**
 If `aka` removed, test passing successfully:

```
   def haveSizeOf(size: Int): Matcher[ProductElement] = { 
        productElement: ProductElement =>
        productElement.size
      } ^^ beEqualTo(size)
```

Comment: That seems more like an error in the assertion. Can you try to manually extract the size in the same way you do in the matcher (or debug it) and check whether it's actually 1?

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia, the assertion is correct, if "aka" removed the test passes. Edited the question to emphasise this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`beEqualTo()` compare a value (like `size`) to `Any` value, including a `org.specs2.matcher.ThrownExpectation` which is the value you build with `aka`. The correct way to build the `haveSizeOf` matcher is

```
def haveSizeOf(size: Int): Matcher[ProductElement] = { 
  productElement: ProductElement =>
  val sizeOfproductElement = productElement.size
  beEqualTo(size).apply(sizeOfproductElement aka "size of product element")
}
```

Each `Matcher[T]` has an `apply` method which accepts values that are of type `Expectation[T]` (basically an expectation is a value of type `T` plus an optional description which you build with `aka`).

Another way to build the same matcher, without reusing `beEqualTo` is

```
def haveSizeOf(size: Int): Matcher[ProductElement] = { 
  productElement: ProductElement =>
  (productElement.size == size,
   s"the size of product element ${productElement.size} is not $size")
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. In the second option, where is the comparison made? I don't see the size that passed as the argument used...

Comment: Sorry, typo. The comparison must be the first element of the pair you return.